# Integrating with respect to random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm having trouble understanding the following. $Z_1,...,Z_n$ are i.i.d. random variables, $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}Z_k$, and $F_{Z_1}(x)$ is the distribution function for $Z_1$.

On to the statement:

$$P(\max_{2 \leq n \leq k+1}(Z_1+(S_n-Z_1)) > u, Z_1 \leq u) = \int_{(-\infty,u]}P(\max_{1 \leq n \leq k} [x+S_n] > u) dF_{Z_1}(x)$$

I don't understand why the $Z_1$ disappears in the $(S_n-Z_1)$ expression. I'm guessing we can rearrange from $2 \leq n \leq k+1$ to $1 \leq n \leq k$ because the $Z_k$'s are i.i.d.?

Edit: Is it because $S_n-Z_1=S_{n-1}$? We go from $n=2$ to $n=k+1$, so in effect we go from $n=1$ to $n=k$, because the $Z_k$'s are i.i.d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usual conditioning method to compute probability. Note that 
$$
Z_1 \perp \!\!\!\perp S_n - Z_1,\quad S_n-Z_1 =_d S_{n-1},
$$ where $\perp\!\!\!\perp$ denotes independence and $X=_d Y$ means $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution function. Noting this, we have for $x\leq u$,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
P(\max_{2 \leq n \leq k+1}(Z_1+(S_n-Z_1)) > u, Z_1 \leq u|Z_1 =x)&=&P(\max_{2 \leq n \leq k+1}(x+(S_n-Z_1)) > u|Z_1 = x)\\&=&P(\max_{2 \leq n \leq k+1}(x+(S_n-Z_1)) > u)\\&=&P(\max_{2 \leq n \leq k+1}(x+S_{n-1}) > u)\\&=&P(\max_{1 \leq n \leq k}(x+S_{n}) > u).
\end{eqnarray}$$ This implies
$$\begin{eqnarray}
P(\max_{2 \leq n \leq k+1}(Z_1+(S_n-Z_1)) > u, Z_1 \leq u)&=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(\max_{2 \leq n \leq k+1}(Z_1+(S_n-Z_1)) > u, Z_1 \leq u|Z_1 =x)dF_{Z_1}(x)\\&=&\int_{-\infty}^u P(\max_{1 \leq n \leq k}(x+S_n) > u)dF_{Z_1}(x),
\end{eqnarray}$$ as desired.